# Is it possible to forward emails to multiple addresses individually using Gmail?

Tags: gmail, gmail-filters, asana

So, at my office we're using Asana for a lot of stuff, but mainly as a project organiser and keeping a tab on support issues from our customers. We're using the "Create task automatically by forwarding an email"-feature of Asana which is working perfectly *unless* the *to*- or *CC*-field of the email contains an email address not recognised by Asana (aka. not registered as a user in our Asana team).

We've set up automatic forwarding using the Gmail filter feature which has worked well until we've been forced to forward the emails to a new email address which is not registered in our Asana team **and** we have no access to. When automatically forwarding emails, Gmail does not seem to send them individually, but rather "clumps" the emails together in the *to*-field. This causes Asana to be unable to process the email since it does not recognise one of the email adresses in the *to*-field.

Thereby my question: is it possible to force Gmail to forward messages to each address individually as to circumvent the problem?

Comment: Make a new filter for that email address.

Comment: It's not clear where the problem is. Is it when Gmail sends email to Asana? The opposite? Is there a reason you couldn't use a Google Group and manage the group of email addresses there, leaving Gmail and Asana to only need to keep track of one email address?